# SSL Connection error when trying to connect to aurora instance

Tags: python, mysql, kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to run a python script through a cronjob inside my EKS cluster. When it tries to connect to my aurora instance, it fails stating that I'm using an unsupported SSL protocol.

[unsupported protocol log trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kbz6F.png)

Any clue? The aurora's mysql version is 5.6, the python is 3.8 and the mysql connector package is 8.0.25

Answer (score 0):

Even though the actual error message is a little different but I'm guessing this is most likely related to the missing TLS certificate issue stated [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-error-2026-ssl-connection/).

You should probably have the certificate available to the pod/cronjob you are trying to run in the cluster.